# Looping through an Array and parsing

Tags: javascript, node-red

I'm using node-red and I have the following incoming msg.payload:

```
[ "=00ECY20WA200_RECV_P1SEL", "true", "=00ECY20WA200_RECV_P2SEL", "true", "=00ECY20WA300_RECV_P2SEL", "true", "=00ECY20WA300_RECV_P1SEL", "true", "=00ECY20WA202_RECV_P1SEL", "true", "=00ECY20WA202_RECV_P2SEL", "false", "=00ECY20WA303_RECV_P2SEL", "true", "=00ECY20WA303_RECV_P1SEL", "true", "=00ECY20WA204_RECV_P1SEL", "false", "=00ECY20WA204_RECV_P2SEL", "true", "=00ECY20WA305_RECV_P2SEL", "false", "=00ECY20WA305_RECV_P1SEL", "false", "=00ECY20WA205_RECV_P1SEL", "false", "=00ECY20WA205_RECV_P2SEL", "false", "=00ECY20WA306_RECV_P1SEL", "true", "=00ECY20WA306_RECV_P2SEL", "true", "=00ECY20WA206_RECV_P1SEL", "false", "=00ECY20WA206_RECV_P2SEL", "true", "=00ECY20WA307_RECV_P1SEL", "true", "=00ECY20WA307_RECV_P2SEL", "true", "=00ECY20WA207_RECV_P1SEL", "false", "=00ECY20WA207_RECV_P2SEL", "false", "=00ECY20WA308_RECV_P1SEL", "false", "=00ECY20WA308_RECV_P2SEL", "true", "=00ECY20WA208_RECV_P1SEL", "false" ]
```

I'm trying to parse all the items which are "true" and concatenate them in an array (recievingAlarms), the parsed item being the one located just before the Boolean operator. I'm trying to do this with a for loop and I'm pretty sure I've created an infinite loop, I'm not sure how to correct it. Here is what I have:

```
var recievingAlarms = [];

for (i = 1; i < msg.payload.length; i+2)
    if(msg.payload[i] === true) {
    recievingAlarms.concat(msg.payload[i-1]);
    }
msg.payload = recievingAlarms;
return msg;
```

Comment: instead of `i+2` use `i+=2`. Change condition `msg.payload[i] === true` to `msg.payload[i] == true`, since `"true"` is a string or compare with string "`true"` instead of boolean `true`. And also `recievingAlarms = recievingAlarms.concat(msg.payload[i-1]);`

Comment: Or even, `msg.payload[i] === 'true'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your solution

```
var recievingAlarms = [];

for (i = 1; i < msg.payload.length; i=i+2)
    if(msg.payload[i] == "true") {
        recievingAlarms=recievingAlarms.concat(msg.payload[i-1]);
    }
msg.payload = recievingAlarms;
return msg;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your loop is infinite right now because you are not incrementing `i`, to increment `i` you would need to replace `i+2` with `i += 2`, in order to reassign its value:

```
var receivingAlarms = [];

for (var i = 1; i < msg.payload.length; i += 2) {
  if(msg.payload[i] === "true") { //replace true with "true"
    receivingAlarms.push(msg.payload[i-1]); //replace concat with push because msg.payload[i - 1] is not an Array
  }
}

msg.payload = receivingAlarms;
return msg;
```

You also need to change `.concat()` to `.push()` - `.concat()` is used for merging/combining two Arrays, but the result of `msg.payload[i-1]` is not an Array.  Also the conditional check for `true` needs to be modified to check for the String `"true"`, since the values in the payload array are Strings not Booleans.

Comment: One little typo there: you forgot to open the brace `{` for the `for` body!

Comment: ahh thanks! will update

Answer (score 1):

1. `i` is never incremented so the condition of the loop will never evaluate to false (`i` will always be less than `.length`).
2. `"true"` and `true` are not of he same type (one is a string and the other is a boolean). Compare `msg.payLoad[i]` to `"true"` instead.
3. `concat` concats two arrays. Use `push` to add a new item to the array.

like this:

```
var recievingAlarms = [];

for (i = 1; i < msg.payload.length; i += 2)
    if(msg.payload[i] === "true")
        recievingAlarms.push(msg.payload[i - 1]);

msg.payload = recievingAlarms;
```